# PostgreSQL function return list of geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a query that return result as expected - list of points.
I would like to create a function with two parameters:

1. input polygon geometry
2. N as number of points to create

   ```
   WITH
   polygon AS 
       (select geometry from property_gis where id=1247675),
   intervals AS 
       (SELECT generate_series (0, 9) as steps)
   SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(polygon.geometry)).geom)), steps/(select count(steps)::float-1 from intervals)) as polygon_points
   FROM
       polygon,intervals;
   ```

I've created next function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_points(polygon geometry)
RETURNS geometry[] AS
$$
DECLARE
    geom_out geometry[];
BEGIN
    WITH
        intervals AS (SELECT generate_series (0, 9) as steps)
        SELECT
            ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(polygon)).geom)),steps/(select 
count(steps)::float-1 from intervals))
        INTO
            geom_out
        FROM
            intervals;

   RETURN geom_out;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

but when I try to call it, like this:

```
with
    poly AS (select geometry from property_gis where id=1247675)
select  get_points(poly.geometry)
from poly;
```

I get the following error:

> [22P02] ERROR: malformed array literal: "01010000000A17E1637B1054C0815E5CA915553A40" Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. Where: PL/pgSQL function get_points(geometry) line 5 at SQL statement

Comment: I guess that you should return a `SETOF geometry` not a `geometry`, check the doc about `SETOF`

Answer (score 3):

I've made changes to have **setof** geometry

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_points(polygon geometry)
RETURNS setof geometry AS
$$
DECLARE
geom_out geometry;
BEGIN

    WITH
    intervals AS (
        SELECT generate_series (0, 9) as steps
    ),
     points as (
            SELECT
                   ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
                       ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(polygon)).geom)),
                       steps/(select count(steps)::float-1 from intervals)
                       ) as point
            FROM intervals
     )
SELECT into geom_out
    point
    FROM
        intervals, points;

RETURN query select geom_out;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

And function call. Now it not crashes, returns only one result , but I need all geometries.

```
with polygon as (
    select geometry from property_gis where id=1247675
)
select get_points(polygon.geometry)
from polygon;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: SELECT into geom_out  * FROM points;